# Are there any instances of space marines getting a prolonged life?

Tags: warhammer-40k

As it is known space marines are not exactly human any longer and have a longer lifespan than humans.

Then there are humans...most notably those of the council that gain prolonged life due to multiple different procedures.

These humans who receive treatment seemingly can live longer than an average space marine. As it seems to me at least in some cases it could be practical to have a space marine life longer than normal. Thus my question: Are there any known instances where the life of a space marine is prolonged beyond the normal lifespan of theirs? (not counting dreadnoughts nor stasis coffins).

Answer (score 8):

They don't die of old age. They only die in battle.

[Dante](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Dante) of the Blood Angels is approximately 1,547 Terran years. Being one of the oldest alive except Bjorn (but he's interred into a dreadnought)
If you count Chaos Space Marines, then Abbadon and most of the leaders are Heresy era marines.

Prolonging the life of a marine is possible, by evading death at the hands of the Xeno or the Heretic. There's also the possibility to lengthen their life through technology, dreadnoughts, stasis, etc.

Comment: I can't remember the story, it is one of the salamander ones, but they find a marine in the 41st millenium who fought alongside Vulkan in the heresy, he isn't in statis is just very very very old. Waiting to be found

Comment: Sounds plausible, I do not know that story, unfortunately. If you remember, please do post it, it sounds nice.

Comment: https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gravius Gravius was his name, details here if you want to add them to your answer

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

### Such Marines are inside Dreadnoughts

> When the greatest of the Astartes are crippled in combat the Battle-Brother's body will be repaired and transferred into an armoured cyborganic sarcophagus outfitted with extensive life support systems. This sarcophagus is then interred within the heart of the armoured body of a Dreadnought if there is even a spark of life left.

As a Dreadnought, Marine can live almost infinitely - Bjorn the Fell Handed is over 10,000 years old. Unfortunately, with age [comes slowly madness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/why-are-dreadnoughts-forgetting-who-they-were), so Dreadnoughs spend most of their time asleep and they are awoken only in the time of need.

Of course, there is also the effect of the Warp - There are many Chaos Space Marines that still remember the Great Crusade and Horus Heresy: while for the material world it has been over 10,000 years, for them it was barely a few decades ago - for example, Kharn the Betrayer was with World Eaters (called back then "War Hounds") before this legion has been united with their primarch Angron, yet he is still alive.

But the premise of the question is bit faulty: saying that there are humans that can live theoretically longer than Astartes is untrue - yes, there are quite a [few life-extending methods](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Extension_Technologies)  - starting from simple medical treatments, through severe mechanical augmentation to sorcery - but the Space Marines don't need them, since they can naturally have a very long lifespan. Mentioned previously Dante is over 1,500 years old. And in the "Salamanders" series, there is a lonely survivor from the Istvaan V massacre, which has taken place almost 10,000 years ago:

> Gravius was the Captain of the Salamanders Legion's 5th Company, during the Great Crusade and he took part in the Conquest of One-Five-Four Four with his friend, Captain Heka'tan[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/why-are-dreadnoughts-forgetting-who-they-were). As the Horus Heresy unfolded, both Captains would take part in the war against the Traitor Legions on Isstvan V, but when the Dropsite Massacre began[2[...]In M41, Gravius was found alive by fellow Salamanders from the Chapter's 3rd Company, but the Captain was now in a horrifically withered and frail state.

Gravious was alive, yet immobile, livig through his sense of duty. In normal circumastances, aging Salamanders seek death, but it is not explained at which age Marine is considered "aging"

> “I don’t know what I believe at this point,” he admitted. “The warp storms could have affected the passage
>   of time. But it’s also entirely possible that this Salamander is simply many years old, longevity being a
>   benefit of our slow metabolic rate. Such a thing has never been tested, given that most of our number
>   invariably meet their end in war or, if death is not forthcoming and age arrives first, by wandering out into
>   the Scorian Plain or setting sail on the Acerbian Sea to find peace. It is the way of the Promethean Creed.”

Last but not least are Primaris Marines - while they appeared recently in the Imperium, their history is as old as Horus Heresy, when Roboute Guilliman charged Archmagos Dominus Cawl with creating a new legion of warriors that would aid the Imperium in its next darkest hour. Cawl was working on this task up to M42 when he finally released the new breed of Marines that was kept all this time in stasis.

Also, I just found about the [Helfathers](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Helfather) - a Iron Hands honor guard that is made entirely from resurrected (and augmented to the point where they are barely alive) warriors. There is a little information about them, but it seems that many of them died more than once, turning them into sort of Imperial Necrons.

Comment: From what OP asked, he wanted to know what marines are alive with modifications (as in mechanical or biological) without being interred into a Dreadnought or stasis. Which is an unknown. Since many books are yet to come, Heresy and 40k, we may yet to see the oldest of marines.

Comment: @Schneejäger Well you could argue that sitting in a Drednought is an EXTREME mechanical modification, since the leftovers or Marine body are connected to complicated machine. Funny enough Iron Hands which are known to follow the "flesh is weak" doctrine (so they are heavily augmented) are not known for longevity

Comment: True, true. I agree with you on this.

Answer (score 1):

While Space Marines might live very long, they are not immortal. From the [German Lexicanum article on Hruds](https://wh40k-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Hrud):

> Selbst Space Marines altern massiv, bis auch sie Altersschwäche zeigen. Es gibt aber auch Berichte über Situationen in denen die Zeit rückwärtslief. Wenn tausende Hrud zusammenkommen sind zudem willkürliche Zeitsprünge wahrgenommen worden. So alterte während der Kämpfe auf Gholghis Kriegsschmied Dantioch um geschätzt 3000 Jahre, wobei er zwischenzeitlich auch wieder ein Junge vor seiner Rekrutierung war.

Translation:

> [Even Space Marines age massively to the point of showing symptoms of old age.](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/The_Iron_Within_(Short_Story)) There are also reports that time ran backwards. [If thousands of Hruds come together, random timejumps can occur. During the battle on Gholghis, Warsmith Dantioch aged by 3000 years but was also turned into a young boy before his recruitment for some time.](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Perturabo:_The_Hammer_of_Olympia_(Novel))

I've linked to the reference where this comes from, you can see the original reference on the Lexicanum-Article.

So, knowing that Dante is one of the oldest living Space Marines and around 1600 years old:

> Dante is the current Chapter Master of the Blood Angels. Commander Dante is one of the most experienced and able Space Marine commanders. In no small part, this is due to the longevity of the Blood Angels, which he has ruled for 1,100 years. Dante is the oldest living Space Marine in the Imperium (excluding Dreadnoughts) and is held in awe by leaders of other Chapters, who can remember him being a famous commander when they were in the Scout Company.
>
> ...
>
> Luis Dante was born in 447.M40 on Baal Secundus (Baal's second moon) and his growth was stunted by malnutrition and radiation.

So, as a Space Marine can age by 3000 years and still be living and knowing that the oldest Space Marine is around 1600 years old, it is safe to assume that no Space Marine has yet reached and age requiring longevity treatment.

But looking at Custodes. Even if custodes are immortal, they get a bit slower in their reaction time with age. At that point, they retire:

> The Custodian Guard do not age biologically, so a veteran officer might be well over a thousand years old. As with all their kind, warriors who believe they are no longer fit for duty will bequeath their armour to the colossal Hall of Names and go abroad into the galaxy disguised under a hooded black cloak.
>
> From the [Lexicanum Article on Adeptus Custodes](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Adeptus_Custodes)

So, with no word it is mentioned that they get longevity treatment. If a member of the Ten Thousand does not get it, I highly doubt that a Space Marine would.

Another point I'd like to make: simply cause the treatment can be used with humans does not mean that it can be used with Space Marines. Describtion of *Rejuvenat* on [Fandom](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Extension_Technologies):

> The use of rejuvenating drugs, usually referred to as "rejuvenat" treatments, is commonplace amongst the middle and upper classes of all technologically advanced Imperial worlds.

However, Space Marines have the Preomnor to filter out drugs and poisons:

> Preomnor
>
> Phase 7: This is essentially a pre-stomach that can neutralise otherwise poisonous or indigestible foods. No actual digestion takes place in the preomnor, as it acts as a decontamination chamber placed before the natural stomach in the body's system and can be isolated from the rest of the digestive tract in order to contain particularly troublesome intake.
>
> From the [enter link description here](http://Lexicanum%20Article%20on%20Creation%20of%20a%20Space%20Marine)

It is possible that even if a Space Marine would get the rejuvenate drugs, he'd maybe not be able to use them. Longevity treatment by technical means, i.e. bionics, is done every time a Space Marine is wounded and requires something new.